# Replacing more than 1 period to 1 period in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have the following code to convert more than one period to one period in a column of a table.

```
alter proc replace_characters_1
@COLUMN_NAME varchar(30),
@TABLE_NAME varchar(30)
as 
    declare @SQL varchar(MAX)
    while @COLUMN_NAME like '%..%'
    begin
    set @SQL= 'update [' +@TABLE_NAME+ '] set [' +@COLUMN_NAME+ '] = replace([' +@COLUMN_NAME+ '],''..'',''.'')';
    exec(@SQL)
end
```

I want to change the `Anna...Amal` to `Anna.Amal` with one go, but the loop is not working. What should I do?`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You want to replace an unknown number of dots with one dot?

Comment: Your while condition is checking the COLUMN_NAME for the occurence of '..', not the actual content of the table with that column name.

Comment: I give the COLUMN_NAME in the execution statement of the stored procedure.

Comment: yes I want to replace multiple numbers of dots to one

Comment: @AnnaSojan I have considered multiple dots. please see my solution

Comment: if I have data in the column like Anna...Amal, Anna..Sojan, and Anna....Honey, I want it to change to Anna.Amal, Anna.Sojan and Anna.Honey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Zhorov's answer as it avoids multiple operations like this one.

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE replace_characters_1
    @COLUMN_NAME varchar(30),
    @TABLE_NAME varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        UPDATE T SET
            ' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + N' = REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + N',''..'',''.'')
        FROM
            ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME) + N' AS T
        WHERE
            T.' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + N' LIKE ''%..%'';

        SET @UpdatedRowsOut = @@ROWCOUNT;';

    DECLARE @UpdatedRows INT = 1;

    WHILE @UpdatedRows > 0
    BEGIN

        EXECUTE sp_executesql 
            @SQL,
            N'@UpdatedRowsOut INT OUTPUT',
            @UpdatedRowsOut = @UpdatedRows OUTPUT;

    END

END
```

Dynamic SQL is now returning the amount of rows that were updated, so it keeps going as long as there are values with `..` for that column (note that there is a `WHERE` filter, you don't want to update all rows every time!).

SQL Server isn't the best for regex expressions, maybe you want to consider using a CLR function if you need to do different kind of stuff with regex.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach is to use nested `REPLACE()`s:

```
SET ColumnName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnName, '.', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', '.')
```

After the first `REPLACE()` the part from the text that contains periods (`.`) looks like  `<><><>`. After the second `REPLACE()` the result is only `<>` and the final `REPLACE()` returns single period (`.`). If the characters `<` and `>` exist in the input text, you can choose another pair of characters.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (Name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO Data (Name)
VALUES
   ('ANNA..Amal'),
   ('ANNA..Amal.'),
   ('ANNA.Amal.'),
   ('ANNA...........Amal.'),
   ('ANNA.....Amal')
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC replace_characters_1
   @COLUMN_NAME sysname,
   @TABLE_NAME sysname
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @RC int

    SET @SQL = 
       N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME) + N' ' +
       N'SET ' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + N' = ' + 
            N'REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + ', ''.'', ''<>''), ''><'', ''''), ''<>'', ''.'') ' +
       N'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + N' LIKE ''%..%'''

    EXEC @RC = sp_executesql @SQL
    RETURN @RC
END
```

Result:

```
EXEC replace_characters_1 N'Name', N'Data'
SELECT * FROM Data

Name
ANNA.Amal
ANNA.Amal.
ANNA.Amal.
ANNA.Amal.
ANNA.Amal
```

Comment: I've had collisions using <>, this is why I pick an extremely rare combination of ‡†

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that will reduce repeating characters.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Anna...Amal')
,('Anna........Amal')
,('Anna.Amal')
,('Anna Amal') 

Select * 
      ,NewVal = replace(replace(replace(SomeCol,'.','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡','.')
 from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
SomeCol             NewVal
Anna...Amal         Anna.Amal
Anna........Amal    Anna.Amal
Anna.Amal           Anna.Amal
Anna Amal           Anna Amal
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I think that nested `REPLACE`s are better option, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I am using CHARINDEX and STUFF to derive the resultset

```
DECLARE @sqlstring Varchar(max) = 'Anna...Amal'
-- Getting first index of .
DECLARE @firstidx INT = CHARINDEX('.',@sqlstring) 
-- Getting last index of .  
Declare @lastidx int = (LEN(@sqlstring) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@sqlstring))) + 1
-- Stuffing the gap with emptystring
SELECT STUFF(@sqlstring,@firstidx+1,(@lastidx-@firstidx),'') as result
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+
|  result   |
+-----------+
| Anna.Amal |
+-----------+
```

**UPDATE**: If there are multiple comma separated values

```sql
    DECLARE @sqlstring Varchar(max) = 'Anna...Amal,Vimal...Mathew'

    SELECT STRING_agg(removedvalues,',') as values
    FROM
    (SELECT STUFF(value, CHARINDEX('.',value)+1
        ,(LEN(value) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(value)) + 1) - CHARINDEX('.',value),'') AS removedvalues
    FROM string_split(@sqlstring,',') ) AS t
```

```
+------------------------+
|         Values         |
+------------------------+
| Anna.Amal,Vimal.Mathew |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: it makes sense. Let me give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: Mark it as answer, if it worked. It will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: This works if there is only one place with dots, if you try with value `Anna...Amal...Mathews` it will return `Anna.Mathews`.

Comment: @EzLo Got it. The requirement is changed. I need to make changes